# How to get a half of every month from current year in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

In my application i have an option to enter the data for every 15days.I have to maintain this for an current year.Please help me to figure out this problem.
For ex: [
            "1-1-2018 to 15-1-2018", "16-1-2018 to 31-1-2018",
            "1-2-2018 to 15-2-2018", "16-2-2018 to 28-2-2018",
            "1-3-2018 to 15-3-2018", "16-3-2018 to 31-3-2018",
            "1-4-2018 to 15-4-2018", "16-4-2018 to 30-4-2018",
            "1-5-2018 to 15-5-2018", "16-5-2018 to 31-5-2018",
            "1-6-2018 to 15-6-2018", "16-6-2018 to 30-6-2018",
            "1-7-2018 to 15-7-2018", "16-7-2018 to 31-7-2018",
            "1-8-2018 to 15-8-2018", "16-8-2018 to 31-8-2018",
            "1-9-2018 to 15-9-2018", "16-9-2018 to 30-9-2018",
            "1-10-2018 to 15-10-2018", "16-10-2018 to 31-10-2018",
            "1-11-2018 to 15-11-2018", "16-11-2018 to 30-11-2018",
            "1-12-2018 to 15-12-2018", "16-12-2018 to 31-12-2018"
        ]

Comment: can you please share some code snippet?

Comment: I just done it static only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Calendar` API you can get total number of days for any month in the given date and also first day of the month like below,

```
extension Calendar {

    public func firstDayOfMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
        let components = self.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: date)
        return  self.date(from: components) ?? date
    }

    public func numberOfDaysInMonthFor(date: Date) -> Int {
        let range = self.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)
        return range?.count ?? 0
    }

    public func lowerHalfOfMonthFor(date: Date) -> (Date, Date) {
        let startDate = self.firstDayOfMonth(date: date)
        let endDate = startDate.dateByAppending(day: 14)

        return (startDate, endDate)
    }

    public func upperHalfOfMonthFor(date: Date) -> (Date, Date) {
        let firstDayOfMonthDate = self.firstDayOfMonth(date: date)
        let totalNoOfDaysInMonth = self.numberOfDaysInMonthFor(date: firstDayOfMonthDate)

        let startDate = firstDayOfMonthDate.dateByAppending(day: 15)
        let endDate = firstDayOfMonthDate.dateByAppending(day: totalNoOfDaysInMonth - 1)

        return (startDate, endDate)
    }
}
```

you can also extend Date to get new date by appending any number of days,

```
extension Date {

    public func dateByAppending(day: Int) -> Date {
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: self)
        return newDate ?? self
    }

    public func daysDifference(_ date: Date?) -> Int? {
        guard let date = date else { return nil }
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: date).day
    }
```

With the mix of above helper methods, you should be able to achieve the required result like below,

```
let date = Date()
let lowerHalf = Calendar.current.lowerHalfOfMonthFor(date: date)
let uppperHalf = Calendar.current.upperHalfOfMonthFor(date: date)
```

Comment: How am use this. i unable to understand.

Comment: i tried it's working perfectly.But i cannot convert the date format as i want.While formatting the date getting an error """cannot convert value of type '(Date, Date)' to expected argument type 'String'"""

Comment: From the error above, i guess your formatting method need string but you are providing tuple.

Comment: let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let str = formatter.string(from: uppperHalf)

Comment: Edit: You need to pass start i.e, 0 or end i.e 1 date from tuple to get the formatted dateString. Currently you are passing tuple so compiler is not accepting that. For example, For StartDate `let startDateString = formatter.string(from: upperHalf.0)` For EndDate `let endDateString = formatter.string(from: upperHalf.1)`

Comment: Hope this will fix the issue and you will get the formatted date!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will calculate the 15th day if you give the input,

```
 static func getFortnightly(selectedDate : String) -> String?{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy" //Your date format
    if let dateSelected = dateFormatter.date(from: selectedDate) {//according to d
      let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 2, to: dateSelected)
      let convertedDateToString = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!)
      return convertedDateToString
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```